# How can one embed Google Wave using Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, gwt, google-wave

How can you embed Google Wave onto Panels in Google Web Toolkit? I've been using the following website as guidance, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. This only works the first time you load the Module and not when you want to load it with an action of a button.

http://groups.google.com/group/gwt-google-apis/browse_thread/thread/fbd79f6cee2a612f?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

This project is created to wrap the Wave Gadget API in Java classes to be able to program Gadgets with GWT.  [here](http://code.google.com/p/cobogwave/) hope this can help